# Вывод информации sql-запросом

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Всем привет! Имеется две таблицы ученик(поля: id, ФИО) и журнал(поля: ID_ученик, оценки, Дата). Требуется sql-запросом вывести ФИО всех учеников, имеющих >5 пятерок и хотя бы одну 4. Вопрос, как это сделать?

Comment: Используйте GROUP BY, HAVING и JOIN.

Comment: Получается должно быть примерно так?
 SELECT ФИО FROM Ученик
JOIN журнал ON Ученик.ID=Журнал.ID and оценки='5' and оценки='4'
GROUP BY ФИО 
HAVING COUNT(*)>5

Comment: Запрос с ошибками, но направление поиска решения в целом верное. Найдите возможность проверить его на тестовой БД.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT s.FIO
FROM students s
JOIN jurnal j ON s.id = j.s_id
GROUP BY s.FIO
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN j.mark = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 5
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN j.mark = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Если не ошибаюсь, то как-то так

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  students st
WHERE
  st.id IN (
    SELECT
      student_id
    FROM
      journal j1
    WHERE
      j1.rate = 5 AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM journal j2 WHERE j2.student_id = j1.student_id AND j2.rate = 4)
    GROUP BY
      j1.student_id
    HAVING
      COUNT(*) > 5
  )
```